# Prevent hardcoding of if condition in bash

Tags: bash

Following is my sample code which is setting environment settings to the session. I am getting env setting name as first argument of the function and storing it to `supplied_env` , I have a list of possible environments which contains possible or allowed environments allowed for this script. I have to keep this list hard coded which is acceptable. However in the end just before sourcing the environment file, I have to run `if condition` with hardcoded environment name(`env1 or env2`). Is there any way to only keep the environment names hardcoded only at the beginning and match them dynamically later ?

```
#!/bin/bash
supplied_env="${1}"
possible_env="env1 env2"

if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
    echo "You must provide any one of these values ${possible_env}"
    exit 1;
elif ! echo "${possible_env}"|grep "$supplied_env" ;then
    echo "Incorrect value provided, You must provide any one of these values ${possible_env}"
    exit 2;
else
    target_env=${supplied_env}
fi

if [ ${supplied_env} == "env1" ];then  #<------How to avoid using `env1` string here, rather get it from possible_env ?
        source ~/.env1
elif [ ${supplied_env} == "env2" ];then
        source ~/.env2
else
   echo "Error..."
fi
```

In short, in future there would be move environments like `env3` ,`env4` etc. I just want to update the script at one place not at multiple places.

Comment: You've already verified that `$supplied_env` is one of the desired values, so just do `source $HOME/.${supplied_env}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if [ ${supplied_env} == "env1" ];then  #<------How to avoid using `env1` string here, rather get it from possible_env ?
>         source ~/.env1
> elif [ ${supplied_env} == "env2" ];then
>         source ~/.env2
> else
>    echo "Error..."
> fi
> ```

You can substitute `$supplied_env` in the `source` statement. Since you've already done error checking you don't need any other logic, just a single `source` call.

```
source ~/."$supplied_env"
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the allowed names as keys in an associative array.

```
declare -A possible_env=([env1]=~/.env1 [env2]=~/.env2)
```

Then you can check for the existence of a key in this array.

```
supplied_env="${1:?Must supply an environment name}"
declare -A possible_env=([env1]=~/.env1 [env2]=~/.env2)

if [[ ! -v possible_env[$suppliedEnv] ]]; then
  echo "Incorrect value provided, You must provide any one of these values: ${!possible_env[*]}"
  exit 2;
fi

source "${possible_env[$suppliedEnv]"
```